# Finite index subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}^2$ that is invariant under a non-singular matrix

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory

Let $M $ be a matrix in $ GL(2, \mathbb{Z})$ that has at least one eigenvalue of absolute value strictly bigger than $1$. What are the finite index subgroups $H$ of $\mathbb{Z}^2$ such that for all $v \in H$, we have $M(v) \in H$?

**Question**: One example of such subgroup has the form  $H=\langle (a,0),(0,a)\rangle$, for a non-zero integer $a$, this example works for any matrix in  $ GL(2, \mathbb{Z})$. I was wondering if there are any other such subgroups.

**Thought so far**: I think the finite index subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}^2$ have the form $\langle (a,b),(c,d)\rangle$, where $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $ad-bc\neq 0$. I was thinking maybe we can use the eigenvectors, but unfortunately the eigenvectors might not have integers entries.

Comment: Which specific matrix $M$? You haven't mentioned any specific matrix $M$. If $M$ has an eigenvalue $\pm 1$ then there will be other invariant subgroups - otherwise probabaly not.

Comment: Sorry before I meant to put "for a specific matrix $M$", as $H=\langle (a,0),(0,a)\rangle$ is invariant under any matrix. I didn't know this property would be affected by the eigenvalues, I edited the question because the matrices I am looking at have an eigenvalue whose absolute value is strictly bigger than $1$.

Comment: Are the subgroups in $\mathbb{Z}^2$ defined by component-wise addition?

Comment: @Mike yes, that's right